# Database or download of Amtrak station codes?

Tags: data-request

Is there available an easily digestible (i.e., CSV or something) source for Amtrak rail station codes?  They have a [code page here](http://www.amtrak.com/html/stations_A.html) but I'm looking for something that could be included in a database lookup, without scraping and building it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scraped and built for you, up on Open Data SE's datahub.io account; note, these are only for America, not all Amtrak stations/codes:
https://datahub.io/dataset/amtrak-stations

2017-04-03 Update:
Added official Amtrak Stations (of U.S.) GeoJSON dataset:
Updated database of the Federal Railroad Administration's (FRA) Amtrak Station database. This database is a geographic data set containing Amtrak intercity railroad passenger terminals in the United States and Canada. Attribute data include services and passenger amenities provided at the station

Official Source:
[Amtrak Stations - US DOT](http://osav-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3e9daf681b154fb19372044f4d52941a_0?geometry=137.049%2C19.855%2C29.999%2C58.749)

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Out of curiosity, did you already have some sort of scraping framework at the ready?  Or just bespoke it?  If I were tackling it myself I'd probably go the python/beautifulsoup route to build something but I don't have the time at the moment to poke at it.

Comment: thought about python/bs route, thought about using importHTML into google sheets, but the structure of each page was so annoying i just copy/pasta'd it

Answer (score 1):

The National Transportation Atlas Database has a shapefile of Amtrak stations

[National Transportation Atlas Database](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index.html)

[Amtrak stations shapefile](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/AdditionalAttachmentFiles/amtrak_sta.zip)